# Why isn't my Log4J code working with the FlumeAppender?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I'm getting the following error with Log4J :

[image]

```
2015-07-07 18:24:00,974 ERROR Error processing element Flume: CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2015-07-07 18:24:01,009 ERROR Appender AuditLogger cannot be located. Route igno
red
```

The following is my Log4J2 XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="OutputLogFile.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>

    <Flume name="AuditLogger" compress="true">
      <Agent host="192.168.10.101" port="8800"/>
      <Agent host="192.168.10.102" port="8800"/>
      <RFC5424Layout enterpriseNumber="18060" includeMDC="true" appName="MyApp"/>
    </Flume>

    <Routing name="Routing">
      <Routes pattern="$${sd:type}">
        <Route>
          <RollingFile name="Rolling-${sd:type}" fileName="${sd:type}.log"
                       filePattern="${sd:type}.%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
              <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100" />
          </RollingFile>
        </Route>
        <Route ref="AuditLogger" key="Audit"/>
      </Routes>
    </Routing>

  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
      <Appender-Ref ref="Console"/>
      <Appender-Ref ref="MyFile"/>  <!-- added_in now -->

    </Root>

  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Then ,  I tried to add in FlumeAppender like this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.flume;
```

But it didn't work after that ... How to set-up FlumeAppender ?

Comment: Change this <Configuration status="WARN"> to <Configuration status="DEBUG"> to see better output about your configuration. If it truly is a class not found exception for the flume appender you may need to update from the beta version of the jar you are using to the latest 2.3 version.

Comment: If you can't determine the problem please post the more verbose output you should get with the status set to DEBUG

Comment: @alan7678  - `update from the beta version of the jar you are using to the latest 2.3 version` - I think this may be my issue .  One question , in my environment variables would I need to point to the `flume-ng.jar` file ? Or is the Flume already in 2.3 ?

Comment: My other issue is that ... now I'm not even sure that Flume is the correct class I need.  It looks like Flume is used to aggregate logs into one massive log library.. but actually I want to split up all my logs into separate logs files ( `logOutput1.log , logOutput2.log, logOutput3.log` ) .   I read about RoutingAppender, but confused as to how to use that

Comment: @alan7678 - Thanks for tip about changin to DEBUG - I'll do this now

Comment: I haven't researched or used the flume appender but according to their website it is in a separate jar. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FlumeAppender

Comment: As far as splitting the logs, do you mean you just want smaller logs with the same output(ie one large file split into 3 smaller ones)? or different output to different files?

Comment: As a start, I'd like to just split the larger logs into smaller logs. But the best would be to have  different output to different files (maybe .. all the DEBUG goes into DEBUG_Log, all the ERROR goes to ERROR_Log , etc)

Comment: Would you know how to do this ? How to make a large log into smaller logs? I know that the variable `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` is for size

Comment: So the real problem with seperating logs by level is that if you have an error, you can't see the debug statements just before it. For example what use is knowing you have a null pointer exception. If you're not told which function/variable it occured. However that is accomplished pretty easily using thresholdfilters. I will post a quick example of a rolling file which will split to smaller logs as we discussed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RollingFile name="MESSAGING_FILE" fileName="log/messaging.log"
             filePattern="log/MM_messaging.log.%i">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n/>
  <Policies>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1MB"/>        
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3"/>
  <Filters>
    <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/> 
  </Filters>
</RollingFile>
```

Here is an example that creates a new file every time the file size becomes 1 MB, you can set the size to standard sizes such as 10 kb 345 MB etc.

The %i in the file pattern must be included for doing the size based rollovers. The max variable determines the number of files it will keep. Over time you will lose the oldest logs.

Lastly the Threshold filter logs only INFO messages and Below ie. (INFO,WARN,ERROR...) to get an exact match set the onMatch to Neutral and then add another Threshold filter like this

```
<Filters>
    <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="NEUTRAL" onMismatch="DENY"/> 
    <ThresholdFilter level="EROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/> 
  </Filters>
```

They get processed in order. Neutral just means move on to the next filter. Accept means it will be immediately logged. If the message gets passed through all the filters with neutral status it will be default accepted just as if there were no filters.

As far as seperating logs by output the most straightforward way is to choose the appenders class path's log to by defining the logger for that path and adding the appender ref to the log you want. Another simple way is to use a marker and markerfilter. Lastly i believe there is also the routingappender which is probably more efficient but more complicated and i don't have experience using it.

Spend some time on the developer website for log4j2 they have a relatively good api reference. It will help you with most everything you want to do in a new implementation.